# Validate method is called with correct parameter when 2 methods are in the same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a method that call a method inside the same class like below:

```
public class ClassSample {

    public MethodA() {
        var objectA = new ObjectA();
        // do somethings with objectA
        return MethodB(objectA)
    }

    public MethodB(ObjectA objectA) {
        // do somethings
    }
}
```

From above block of code, if I want to test that after do somethings in methodA then MethodB with correct parameter.

Comment: Please provide more description. Now question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `MethodB` as verifiable,

```
 mock.Setup(p => p.MethodB(It.Is<ObjectA>(q => q.status == true))).Verifiable();
```

Check below code snippet,

```
    public class ObjectA
    {
        public ObjectA()
        {
        }

        public bool status { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassSample
    {

        public ObjectA MethodA()
        {
            var objectA = new ObjectA();
            // do somethings with objectA
            objectA.status = true;
            return MethodB(objectA);
        }

        public ObjectA MethodB(ObjectA objectA)
        {
            // do somethings
            return objectA;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestClassSample()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ClassSample>();
        mock.Setup(p => p.MethodB(It.Is<ObjectA>(q => q.status == true))).Verifiable();

        var result = mock.Object.MethodA();

        mock.Verify();
    }
```